# generate SEQUENCE on next day it will initialize using Psycopg

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql-9.1

Using PostgreSQL and Python  we want to generate the sequence based on daily basis such that  next day comes the sequence starts with 1 .

We are using tryton framework.

Ex:
**201402170001(year month day 0001) this day generate more than 100 sequence,the next day it will start from 201402180001**.

We generate the sequence. But we not have idea how the every nextday it should be initilaze?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strftime` to get the date string and use string formatting to pad some incrementing `counter` to four digits:

```
from datetime import datetime

counter = 1
datestr = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
sequence = "{0}{1:04d}".format(datestr, counter)
```

---

To update the counter daily, you will need to store the current day, then reset to 1 when it changes, e.g.:

```
if current_date != datetime.today():
    counter = 1 # reset counter
    current_date = datetime.today() # update current_date
```

Comment: thanks.it will work.But we worked on tryton framework.We generate the sequence.But not have idea to initialize every next day